# Is Playsound able to play two sounds at the same time?

Tags: python, python-playsound

When you press `e` it will play the sound, which is fine. But when you try to press it while the sound is active it waits until the sound is done to play it again. I need the sounds to be played at the same time.

```
import tkinter
from playsound import playsound

root = tkinter.Tk()

def key_pressed(event):
    playsound('sound.wav')

root.bind("<Key>", key_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: first idea that comes to mind is using threading

Comment: @Matiiss Could you explain threading?

Comment: well as far as I understand it means that You run another thread in paralle or more like concurrently but then look at multiprocessing, look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEEhzQoKtQU)

Comment: @Matiiss Multiprocessing? Yea I don't think that will work.

Comment: why not? have You tried?

Comment: @Matiiss I have tried it on other scripts and what i'm thinking for this isn't exactly going to work with multiprocessing

Comment: Have you tried adding `block=False` option?

Comment: @CoolCloud No, how would I do this?

Comment: @CoolCloud Hold up it worked.

Comment: @Lloyd wow, I almost made a whole workaround around this issue and was planning on using various libraries. luckily I took a look at the comments

Comment: @Matiiss Yea `pygame` is an alternative, but using a big library for just its mixer seems overkill considering this small project.

Comment: @CoolCloud nah I was thinking of using playsound just also add some `_thread` and `keyboard` and make sure to check focus and probably more but sure, `pygame` would also probably help, but this is like one argument to the function and it solves the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import tkinter
from playsound import playsound

root = tkinter.Tk()

def key_pressed(event):
    playsound('sound.wav', block=False)

root.bind("<Key>", key_pressed)
root.mainloop()
```